# SQL Queries in Visual Studio C#

Tags: sql-server, plugins, visual-studio-2012

Is there a plugin for Visual Studio that can show my mssql strings as actual queries, with highlighting and if possible intellisense.

I don't want to discuss why the queries are in code, it is a running project and that decision has already been made for me.

The code now:

`string sql = @"select * from A where a.Id = @pId"`

What I want is the above to be highlighted, so it looks like a query, so it shows select and where as actual sql. What I need is some sort of analyzer plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you could take a look at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3a662c6-28eb-4de9-9a29-d328b1ac3f6b for a possible fix to your problem.